# What causes increases in city tile bonuses?

Tags: civilization-5-brave-new-world

I’ve seen lots of cities with huge tile bonuses, like in the screenshot. What exactly causes these bonuses to increase? Also, is there a way in-game to find what exactly is causing the bonuses on a city tile?

[image]

Comment: City tile yields are almost entirely dependent upon the buildings that exist in the city.

Comment: Yields are usually affected by the buildings in your city, any research you have done and tile improvements.

Answer (score 2):

Your city yield is the total amount of resources that your city generates. It is basically the total output of every single tile that your city is currently working.

You can increase your city output in two ways:

1. Tile Improvements
   *Tile improvements increase the amount of output that a tile produces. For example, a farm on will increase food output by +2.*
2. City Buildings
   *City buildings will increase the total resource that it generates. For example, a Factory will boost your city's current production output by 10% and adds +4 production it.*
3. Great Persons (still considered as "Tile Improvements")
   *Great persons, when consumed to create a building will give resources to the closest city. For example, the Great Merchant will become a Customs House, which adds +10 GPT (Gold per turn) to the tile it is applied to.*